# Why is my computer not running VIrtualBox correctly?

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox, dpkg

When I run VirtualBox, I get the following output:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I tried running `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms` and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`. I even tried removing and reinstalling them. I have also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox`. I have also tried starting a VM anyway: maybe the error message was wrong. The window that came up said the following:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or 
there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install 
virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install 
the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel 
changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The 
support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

So I ran `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` and this was the output:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
```

But nothing has solved my problem. I still can't start virtual machines. Is there something I haven't tried? How do I get my device to run Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely getting impacted by the recent tightening of Secure Boot restrictions.  I had to turn off Secure Boot to get Virtualbox to run.

If you are running a 64 bit UEFI system, turn off Secure Boot, and you should be able to install it properly.

Comment: How do I turn off secure boot?

Comment: It's a setting in your PC's UEFI (sometimes incorrectly still referred to as BIOS).  Unfortunately it's different for every manufacturer.  You have to press a key during boot to enter the UEFI interface, then find the secure boot setting, and disable it.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653226 google for your pc's manufacturer and disable secure boot

Comment: Thanks. After some extensive searching, I found it. It turns out, disabling secure boot worked.

Comment: This recent change was not well documented and has caused a lot of people problems.  Glad it worked.